# Document Library View filter on term

Tags: document-library, view, term-store, term

Say I have a view that has a column based on metadata from my termset. I want to create a view that contains all the items that are tagged in one parent term and its child terms. For example:

A view called "Fund Documents" would contain anything with:

Fund Documents

- Certificates
- Legal

So if a document is tagged "certificates" it should show up in the  view, or if it is tagged "Fund Documents"  it should also show up.

I hope I am making sense...

I would like to do this without explicitly entering all the child categories as well as the parent in the view filter settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot filter the managed metadata for the parent and also return child terms when creating a view.

An alternative is to turn on metadata navigation. This would give you a navigation control on the left hand side of the page to filter by fields. Clicking on a top level term here would also show all the items with sub terms.

This can be accessed from the Library Settings. Under the General Settings section there is a Metadata navigation settings link.